# Accessing composable function from within non-composable function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way, using Android Jetpack Compose, to access a composable function or an `ambientOf` value from within a non-composable function?

For instance, I have a `val` in `MainActivity` that I would like to access/modify from within a non-composable function. Is this possible? If so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Could you improve this question and/or provide your scenario?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your mental model of composable functions isn't quite right here.  Calling a composable function from within a non-composable function doesn't make sense.

For your specific example of `ambientOf`, the ambient value doesn't exist outside of composition—you can think of an ambient as being supplied to everything "below" it in the composition tree. Accessing it outside of that tree doesn't work: you can't read it because it doesn't exist outside of the tree (it would always have no value even if you could), and you can't write to it because there's no corresponding location in the tree.

Comment: In spite of this example's being due to a misunderstanding, still it would be nice to be able to create and run a `@Composable` context.  This would enable unit testing of higher order functions without spinning up an emulator.